# Current selected value in angular6 material mat-selection-list

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular6

Working with Angular Material2 **mat-selection-list**, Able to identify whether current option is selected or non-selected[Boolean].

**compnenent.html**

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes (selectionChange)="onSelection($event, shoes.selectedOptions)" >
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" [value]='shoe'>
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class ListSelectionExample {
  typesOfShoes = ['Boots', 'Clogs', 'Loafers', 'Moccasins', 'Sneakers'];

  onSelection(e, v){
   console.error(e.option.selected,v); 
  }
}
```

`e.option.selected` notifies whether current option is selected or non-selected.

How to identify current selected value ?  Tried with multiple combinations with **ngModel  and ngModelChange** and **click** , nothing works for me.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyjdfp-qgjhvd?file=app%2Flist-selection-example.ts

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get current selected value by getting `e.option.value` of your selectionChange `$event`

**component.ts**

```
current_selected: string;

onSelection(e, v){
   this.current_selected = e.option.value;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<p>
  Current selected value: {{ current_selected }}
</p>
```

**Bonus**

You can list all selected items by calling property selected of `shoes.selectedOptions.selected` in the template.

**component.html**

```
<p>Selected:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let i of shoes.selectedOptions.selected">
    {{ i.value }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-selected-items)**

Comment: I always get undefined for e.option.value using ang 7/mat 7

Comment: same here, I am also getting undefined for e.option.value

Answer (score 8):

Use the `click` event binding on the `mat-list-option`:

```html
<mat-selection-list #shoes (selectionChange)="onSelection($event, shoes.selectedOptions)" >
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" [value]='shoe' (click)="getValue($event)">
        {{shoe}}
      </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Component TypeScript:

```ts
getValue(event){
    console.log(event.target.parentNode.innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In recent Angular versions you should use `options`:

In your template:

```
<mat-selection-list [multiple]="false" (selectionChange)="selChange($event)">
```

In your class:

```
public selChange(e: MatSelectionListChange) {
    let selection = e.options[0].value;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you don't have **[(ngModel)]=** within your mat-selection-list element overriding your selectionChange from within the selChange method.

Comment: This does't work. The e.options[0].value is always undefined.

Answer (score 4):

```
 <mat-selection-list class="addressList" #userAddressList>
          <mat-list-option *ngFor="let userAddress of userAddressesArray"
          (click)="onAddressSelection(userAddress)">
                  {{userAddress}}
                </mat-list-option>
              </mat-selection-list>
In TypeScript


  private onAddressSelection(selectedItem:any) {
   let  selectedOption = selectedItem;


  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I spent a good amount of time in finding a solution for this, but everything in vain...
Fortunately enough I have come up with an idea for it, hope it helps.

----checkListItems is the array which consists of all the items that I want to publish----

### component.html

```
<mat-selection-list #checkItems (selectionChange)="onSelection($event, checkItems.selectedOptions.selected)">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let check of checklistItems">
    {{check.label}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

In mat-selection-list I am sending an event and the **value** of all the selected items, so this **value** that I am talking about is actually an array of MatSelectionList. And I have to parse the value of my selected item in my .ts file.

### component.ts

```
selectedOptions = [];
checkedValues = [];

onSelection(event, value) {
    this.checkedValues = [];
    this.selectedOptions = value;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
      this.checkedValues.push(this.selectedOptions[i]._text.nativeElement.innerText);
    }
}
```

So, I have an array called checkedValues, which I am deleting every time a selection or deselection is being done, as MatSelectionList array (in this case my **value** array) will consist of all the items that are selected. So if you won't delete it every time, it will keep on appending the same item every time it is selected. (You can try this by removing the line **this.checkedValues=[]** and printing the checkedValues array after for loop gets finished).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: rather than use `_text.nativeElement.innerText` you could add `[value]='check.label'` to your `mat-list-option` then you can use `value.map( m => m.value)`

Answer (score 1):

In your component 
.ts :

```
export class ListSelectionExample {
 typesOfShoes = ['Boots', 'Clogs', 'Loafers', 'Moccasins', 'Sneakers'];

 selectedShoes;

 onSelection(e, v){
   this.selectedShoes = v.selected.map(item => item.value);

  console.error(e.option.selected,v); 
 }
}
```