# Getting list of selected values from Angular 6 mat-selection-list

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

How do I get the list of all values selected from Angular material [mat selection list](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatSelectionList) in the component. The example given shows values to be displayed in the template but not in component. I am trying to modify the solution given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636365/current-selected-value-in-angular6-material-mat-selection-list/50636719) but its not working for me. Here is my current code:

Template:

```
<mat-selection-list #selected [(ngModel)]="readingTypesSelected" (ngModelChange)="onSelection($event)" >
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let readingType of readingTypes">
    {{readingType.name}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Component:

```
    onSelection(e, v) {

    console.log(e);
    console.log(v);    
  }
```

The following is getting logged to console:

[image]

How do i extract actual values of selected options from this?

**Solution**:

The first two lines of template code should be (as given in stackblitz link in accepted solution):

```
<mat-selection-list #selected (selectionChange)="onSelection($event, selected.selectedOptions.selected)" >
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let readingType of readingTypes" [value] ="readingType">
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I am getting an array with MatListOption as values. Don't know how to extract the actual values.

Comment: Solution you mentioned works for Angular 8, Materials 8 too..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your stackblitz code here https://angular-selection.stackblitz.io

Now you can get selected values in console.

Comment: I am not able to get the code from stackblitz. Can you please paste the code here?

Comment: Possibly this will be his stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selection

Comment: and a possible duplicate of this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-selected-items

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
<mat-selection-list #list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" [value]="shoe">
      {{shoe}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

After binding `[(ngModel)]="selectedOptions"` you can use `selectedOptions` variable in your component which will have all selected items.

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdmfwi

Comment: This didn't work. Please note this is for Angular 6. I have edited the question with my code. Please check.

Comment: Works in angular 11

Answer (score 3):

This solution is better

```
selectionChanged(event: MatSelectionListChange): void {
    this.selected = event.options.filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code value attribute is missing

Replace:

```html
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let readingType of readingTypes">
```

with:

```html
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let readingType of readingTypes" [value]="readingType">
```

and then get the selected array in `readingTypesSelected`,

`readingTypesSelected` is mentioned in `[(ngModel)]="readingTypesSelected"`

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-selection-list #products [(ngModel)]="selectedProducts">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let eachProduct of allProducts;" [value]="eachProduct">
        {{eachProduct.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

{{selectedProducts|json}}
```

Tested in Angular 10. The main part is `[value]="eachProduct"` other wise it will show `null`

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<mat-selection-list 
  #selectionList
  (selectionChange)="listSelectionChange($event)"
>
   <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" [value]="shoe">
    {{shoe}}
   </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

ts

```
listSelectionChange(e: MatSelectionListChange) {
  console.log(e.source.selectedOptions.selected.map((o: MatListOption) => o.value));
}
```

enjoy!